# MInt 17.2, Enable Icon display for root desktop? Eg Home, Computer,etc

Tags: linux-mint

Is it possible to enable icon display for the root desktop? I tried the System Settings > Desktop config utility, but that doesn't display the icons. Is there a config file somewhere?

The desktop environment is Cinnamon. The file manager is Nemo, and running it doesn't cause the icons to appear on the desktop.

Comment: The file manager is probably not running. Open a terminal and run `nautilus` or `caja` or whichever file manager they're using these days. Does that make the icons appear?

Comment: The file manager is Nemo, and running it doesn't cause the icons to appear on the desktop. Thks, tho.

Comment: OK, please [edit] your question and include that detail and also tell us what desktop environment you're running. Note that some file managers don't even let you run them as root (as I recall, anyway). Finally, it might be a good idea to explain why you need this. If you've been using *nix for 15 years, you know it is very stupid to always log in as root and there is rarely any reason to do so from the GUI. Could you explain what your final objective is?

Answer (score 0):

Install gnome-tweak-tool to be able to turn icons on and off on the desktop including the root desktop. Ubuntu-tweak is more popular, but it can't find the package. Google "gnome tweak".